# How to call a non-void function? Xcode

Tags: iphone, function, methods, void

How do I call a non-void function? Normal `[self methodName];` works. But how do I do this for a method that returns an `NSString`. I keep getting an error. For example:

```
+ (NSString *)formulateYQLRequestFor:(NSArray *)tickers
```

How do I call this? `[self formulateYQLRequestFor];` gives me an error.

Sorry about the formatting, for some reason safari won't let me indent. 
Thanks!

Comment: The "+" indicate a class method, and you need to put an array (or nil if the method check the parameter).

Comment: [[self class] formulateYQLRequestFor:[NSArray new]];

Answer (score 1):

`+` designates a class function. You call it with the class name, not an instance.

Instead of:

```
[self formulateYQLRequestFor:myArray];
```

Do this:

```
[MyClassName formulateYQLRequestFor:myArray];
```

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
[[self class] formulateYQLRequestFor:myArray];
```

You don't have to do anything with the return value if you don't want to. At least with ARC, the return value will be automatically released. However, since it's unlikely that the function does anything on its own, you probably should do something with the return value:

```
NSString *returnValue = [[self class] formulateYQLRequestFor:myArray];
// Do something with returnValue
```

Finally, if you want to call the function without passing in an array, you still need the array parameter, but perhaps the function will accept `nil` for the array:

```
NSString *returnValue = [[self class] formulateYQLRequestFor:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `- (NSString *)formulateYQLRequestFor:` does with the NSArray, but if it isn't necessary you can just call `[self formulateYQLRequestFor:nil];`. Alternatively you can call it with an empty array `[self formulateYQLRequestFor:[NSArray array]];`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your call to `[self formulateYQLRequestFor];`

Firstly, the method takes a parameter, which you haven't provided. Because of this, the compiler is looking for the method called `formulateYQLRequestFor` instead of `formulateYQLRequestFor:` This is significant, because the `:` is part of the method name in Objective-C. So you are trying to call a method that doesn't exist.

Secondly, `self` is sending a message to an **instance** of your class. The `+` in the method signature indicates that you have a class method, and so `self` does not respond to the method you are trying to call.

The correct way to do this is:

```
NSString *resultString = [[self class] formulateYQLRequestFor:someArray];
```

where `someArray` is a valid `NSArray` parameter.